# How do i store the json response from my server to an arraylist and pass to next activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I am using Retrofit and the server returns `JSON` object as response. I want to store it in an `ArrayList` and pass it to the next activity where it can be displayed in `RecyclerView`. I am not getting any error but there is no output on the Display activity. What could be the problem?

Here is my main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public static final String ROOT_URL = "http://walletuncle.com/";

String username;
String password;

private Button makerequest;

private ProgressDialog pdialog;

private EditText edittextusername;
private EditText edittextpassword;

private String DataArray[] = new String[15];

private ArrayList<Result> dataarr = new ArrayList<>();

int i = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    makerequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnObjRequest);


    edittextpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpassword);
    edittextusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editusername);

    pdialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pdialog.setMessage("wait kar be...");
    pdialog.setCancelable(false);


    makerequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            makejsonobjectrequest();
        }
    });


}


private void makejsonobjectrequest() {


    username = edittextusername.getText().toString().trim();
    password = edittextpassword.getText().toString().trim();


    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL)
            .build();


    //creating object of our interface
    DataApi data = adapter.create(DataApi.class);

    //defining the method.
    data.getposition(username, password, new Callback<Result>() {


        @Override
        public void success(Result result, Response response) {


            dataarr = result;


            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putSerializable("array", dataarr);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Display.class);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    });
}


}
```

my interface for retrofit is:

```
public interface DataApi {

//retrofit to get annotation with our url.

@GET("/myservice.asmx/UserLogin")
 void getposition(@Query("UserId") String userid, @Query("password") String password, Callback<Result> result);

}
```

Comment: check using log , Is your response coming or not ?

Comment: E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering

Comment: this seems be an error i found in debugging

Comment: set this to your `failure()` method 
           `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` . and in `sucess()` also `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), strings.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` . you get idea about some error happen on REST API call or Not ....

Comment: apparently the response is not a success from the server side.

Comment: that means you have done many mistakes in your call

Comment: try with this `@GET("myservice.asmx/UserLogin")`

Comment: yes, could you tell me my mistakes please?

Comment: now the error is: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.illegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path$

Comment: please send me the POSTMAN response ...... Bcoz you have to create POJO class of that response .

Comment: {
  "phoneno": "0",
  "comission": "0",
  "Status": "false",
  "memberid": "12121",
  "mid": 0,
  "CARD": "0",
  "Name": "Incorrect User Id & Password",
  "msgcount": "0",
  "WalletAmount": "0",
  "mtype": 0,
  "RewardPoints": 0,
  "totalcusto": "0",
  "monthcusto": "0",
  "notify": false,
  "notification": "0"
}

Comment: this is the response.

Comment: have look on  answer added the POJO with some points ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128516/discussion-between-sushildlh-and-choi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> instead of `Callback<ArrayList<String>> cb`
>
> use this `Callback<Result> result` in your interface ...
>
> and do changes in your Retrofit call also .
>
> instead of this `<ArrayList<String>>`
>
> use like this `<Result>`.....

use this POJO class ....

```
public class Result implements Serialization {

@SerializedName("phoneno")
@Expose
private String phoneno;
@SerializedName("comission")
@Expose
private String comission;
@SerializedName("Status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("memberid")
@Expose
private String memberid;
@SerializedName("mid")
@Expose
private Integer mid;
@SerializedName("CARD")
@Expose
private String cARD;
@SerializedName("Name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("msgcount")
@Expose
private String msgcount;
@SerializedName("WalletAmount")
@Expose
private String walletAmount;
@SerializedName("mtype")
@Expose
private Integer mtype;
@SerializedName("RewardPoints")
@Expose
private Integer rewardPoints;
@SerializedName("totalcusto")
@Expose
private String totalcusto;
@SerializedName("monthcusto")
@Expose
private String monthcusto;
@SerializedName("notify")
@Expose
private Boolean notify;
@SerializedName("notification")
@Expose
private String notification;

/**
* 
* @return
* The phoneno
*/
public String getPhoneno() {
return phoneno;
}

/**
* 
* @param phoneno
* The phoneno
*/
public void setPhoneno(String phoneno) {
this.phoneno = phoneno;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The comission
*/
public String getComission() {
return comission;
}

/**
* 
* @param comission
* The comission
*/
public void setComission(String comission) {
this.comission = comission;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The status
*/
public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

/**
* 
* @param status
* The Status
*/
public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The memberid
*/
public String getMemberid() {
return memberid;
}

/**
* 
* @param memberid
* The memberid
*/
public void setMemberid(String memberid) {
this.memberid = memberid;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The mid
*/
public Integer getMid() {
return mid;
}

/**
* 
* @param mid
* The mid
*/
public void setMid(Integer mid) {
this.mid = mid;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The cARD
*/
public String getCARD() {
return cARD;
}

/**
* 
* @param cARD
* The CARD
*/
public void setCARD(String cARD) {
this.cARD = cARD;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The name
*/
public String getName() {
return name;
}

/**
* 
* @param name
* The Name
*/
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The msgcount
*/
public String getMsgcount() {
return msgcount;
}

/**
* 
* @param msgcount
* The msgcount
*/
public void setMsgcount(String msgcount) {
this.msgcount = msgcount;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The walletAmount
*/
public String getWalletAmount() {
return walletAmount;
}

/**
* 
* @param walletAmount
* The WalletAmount
*/
public void setWalletAmount(String walletAmount) {
this.walletAmount = walletAmount;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The mtype
*/
public Integer getMtype() {
return mtype;
}

/**
* 
* @param mtype
* The mtype
*/
public void setMtype(Integer mtype) {
this.mtype = mtype;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The rewardPoints
*/
public Integer getRewardPoints() {
return rewardPoints;
}

/**
* 
* @param rewardPoints
* The RewardPoints
*/
public void setRewardPoints(Integer rewardPoints) {
this.rewardPoints = rewardPoints;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The totalcusto
*/
public String getTotalcusto() {
return totalcusto;
}

/**
* 
* @param totalcusto
* The totalcusto
*/
public void setTotalcusto(String totalcusto) {
this.totalcusto = totalcusto;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The monthcusto
*/
public String getMonthcusto() {
return monthcusto;
}

/**
* 
* @param monthcusto
* The monthcusto
*/
public void setMonthcusto(String monthcusto) {
this.monthcusto = monthcusto;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The notify
*/
public Boolean getNotify() {
return notify;
}

/**
* 
* @param notify
* The notify
*/
public void setNotify(Boolean notify) {
this.notify = notify;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The notification
*/
public String getNotification() {
return notification;
}

/**
* 
* @param notification
* The notification
*/
public void setNotification(String notification) {
this.notification = notification;
}

}
```

**EDIT:-**

use this code instead of your

```
private Result result;  // create this as global


 data.getposition(username, password, new Callback<Result>() {


            @Override
            public void success(Result res, Response response) {

                result = res;
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Display.class);
                intent.putExtra("data",(Serializable)result);
                startActivity(intent);


            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: How do i save the response in an arraylist or an array?

Comment: where you have to store the array , there is no array inside the JSON ....

Comment: i want to store each value in an arraylist so that i can display it in recyclerview.

Comment: DataArray[i]  = "Name" + ":" + response.getString("Name");

Comment: this is how i did with volley but its not clear how to do it with retrofit.

Comment: in retrofit find this `ArrayList<String>` and replace with this `Result`

Comment: As u said i made the changes but its still not working. please see the question for edited code.

Comment: how do i pass it in intent?

Comment: have look on answer and also update the POJO class , small change :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128527/discussion-between-choi-and-sushildlh).

Comment: there is an error which says "register an Instancecreator with Gson may solve this problem."

Comment: so how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Move this block in success method. As its an Async call, you will not get the result instantly, so wait for response and then pass it to another *Activity*.

```
@Override
public void success(ArrayList<String> strings, Response response) {

    dataarr = strings;
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putStringArrayList("array", dataarr);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Display.class);
    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: now the next activity is not opening which means that there is no sucessful response from the server. what's wrong there?

Comment: So the basic idea is not go to next screen, till you get positive response.

Comment: retrofit: Retrofit: 500 internal Server Error.

Comment: But i checked postman the server side is fine also i did this successfully with volley.

Comment: yes because in this api i need to append the data manually to get the response. this is how i did it using volley.

Comment: http://walletuncle.com/myservice.asmx/UserLogin?UserId=12121&password=1215

Comment: this is the api that will give the json response, we need to append the userid and password.

Comment: String uri = String.format("http://walletuncle.com/myservice.asmx/UserLogin?UserId=%1$s&password=%2$s",
                username,
                password);

Comment: this is how i did it with volley.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128510/discussion-between-rahul-kapoor-and-choi).