# How to get json response from Server and store them in an Arraylist using Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to get Json response from the server and pass it in intent as an arraylist to the next activity. This worked fine with volley but i am unable to get response via retrofit. Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public static final String ROOT_URL = "http://#####.####/";

String username;
String password;

private Button makerequest;

private ProgressDialog pdialog;

private EditText edittextusername;
private EditText edittextpassword;

private String DataArray[] = new String[15];

private ArrayList<Result> dataarr = new ArrayList<>();

int i=0;






@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    makerequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnObjRequest);


    edittextpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpassword);
    edittextusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editusername);

    pdialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pdialog.setMessage("wait kar be...");
    pdialog.setCancelable(false);


    makerequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            makejsonobjectrequest();
        }
    });


}


private void makejsonobjectrequest(){


    username = edittextusername.getText().toString().trim();
    password = edittextpassword.getText().toString().trim();


    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL)
            .build();


    //creating object of our interface
    DataApi data = adapter.create(DataApi.class);

    //defining the method.
    data.getposition(username, password, new Callback<ArrayList<Result>>() {


                @Override
                public void success(ArrayList<Result> list, Response response) {




                   dataarr= list;



                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putSerializable("array", dataarr);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Display.class);
                    intent.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(intent);


                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });

}
}
```

Comment: the error is: retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:java.lang.illegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line1 column 2 path $.

Comment: post here response JSON using POSTMAN . this error coming bcoz json start with simple object , but you are trying to get it into ArrayList . Have look on it same problem like you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40689691/how-do-i-store-the-json-response-from-my-server-to-an-arraylist-and-pass-to-next/40690138#40690138

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link you will get json response using retrofit library http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

Answer (score 0):

Usually this kind of error comes when the response you expect doesn't come from Server.

i think you should first check your the response which comes from server is in correct format so that your application can parse it correctly.

if you are using android studio you can see the request you are sending and the Url used for that request in android monitor after sending the request , try to use an application like https://www.getpostman.com/ to send your request and see if you get correct response from Server.

hope this helps.